# CSS height not working if body has min-height

Tags: html, css, layout, height

I don't get my first child in the body to 100% height, if the body has `min-height` specified.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
                height:100%;
            }
            body {
                min-height:100%;
            }
            #wrapper {
                height:100%;
                min-width:1120px; /* 250px each side (content width is 870px) */
                max-width:2000px;
                background-image:url(bg.png);
                background-position:50% 25px;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- web content -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This does **not** resize the wrapper to the height of the window. When I remove the `min-` and use `height`, it'll work. But I have to have the content height variable...

I did find some other posts here on SO and on google, but they have just questions and no solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually found a solution!

Now I have:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

So my body is not `min-height`. I don't remember why I changed it to `min-height`, but I hope I won't face the issue I obviously faced some time ago...

Comment: But you stated in your question that you already knew it works with `height` :).

Comment: I don't know what happened there, somehow it all got screwed up, but now it works - don't get it :)

Comment: But in this case, You can't use PageUp/Down and page always scroll up after reload

Comment: This will break other pages of your website if they have more than 100% height in content. My answer explains how to get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 22):

When you use a percentage value for `height`, it will always be relative to the specified `height` of the parent element. Not the actual height of the parent element, but the `height` specified in CSS.

So when your `body` element has no `height` specified (only `min-height`, but that does not count), the `100%` will not be able to take effect.

One possible solution is to use `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;` on your `#wrapper`, and your div will be stretched. This of course might have some layout consequences that you do not want.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u7W7W/)

Comment: I already feared that fact :( I'm trying to have my `#wrapper` going to bottom under every circumstances. So if the content is smaller, it has to be 100% of the html, otherwise it has to be as high as the content. And that does not work with `position:absolute`. Sad it seems to be unachievable. But many thanks. Any other ideas are still appreciated ;)

Comment: I did find a solution... I actually already had that, so I don't remember why I changed it

Comment: @Julian Well, if you put `overflow: auto` on your absolute positioned wrapper it will certainly *look* fine. I don't know exactly what are the special requirements though. But hm... don't you want `min-height` on your `#wrapper` element instead of `body` if I get it right?

Comment: Jep - right. But the body itself was not big enough and somehow it was all screwed up

Answer (score 11):

### Short Answer

Use `height:100vh;` for divs you want to stretch and fill the screen.

**Do not** set body's `height: 100%;` It will break your entire site if you have pages that have more than 100% in content height. They won't be able to scroll.

### Long Answer

If you want a few pages of your website to fill the entire screen while still allowing other pages to scroll (because they have more than 100% height in content), you need to set the div height to 100%, not the entire site-wide body height.

Use this as general site-wide css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Then set specific divs to fill the entire screen (when they have less than 100% height in content):

```
/* Set any div heights to 100% of the screen height*/
.div {
    height:100vh;
}
```

Explanation of the vh measurement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/4975772

Comment: This saved my day

Comment: Sorry but ... no  On the mobile device the top url bar is not taken into account in the calculation of the viewport (vh) so a scroll appears with this technique

Comment: @ApynAOM Unfortunately this was an intentional decision by the developers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113430/4975772) Trying to give a truly fullscreen experience on mobile requires a lot more effort than just this one css setting. This article looks helpful if that's what you're going for. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/