# min-height|height html, body acting strange

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website that have pages that exceed `100% browser window height` and ones that *do not*. So, what I need is the height to be at least `100%` but higher if applicable.

My current `CSS` looks like:

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This initially seemed to work fine but then I realized that `<body>` does *NOT* have the same `height` as `<html>` but rather seems to use the standard `height`. It is like `<body>` does *NOT* respect the `min-height` property.

Hopefully, someone can toss some ideas or shine some light on this.

**UPDATE1** It seems like HTML is acting as if it was default too..

**UPDATE2** http://jsfiddle.net/rpz4rd4c/5

**UPDATE3** According to the suggested comment by ( MichaelHarvey ) the `body height` is relative to the `html height` ( not `min-height` ) if that was true the following code should work:

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

However, it doesn't.

**FINAL UPDATE**

The solutions provided on this page "work" however they might be buggy with JS plugins. I would recommend people to use `100vh` solution or the one I accepted as answer ( mainly because it requires no `CSS3` ). I guess a 100% accurate solution to a problem like mine (having all dividers and elements 100% non-related to browser window) would be to simply use `inline CSS` and use `min-height` at longer pages and a `height` at browser fitting ones. This might require some `JS`.

<3

Comment: Can you give us a link or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: @Adrift http://jsfiddle.net/rpz4rd4c/

Comment: See if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20681480/3781639

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I did specify a height. So, no it doesn't really help me.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The problem is that the `body` is not relative to the height of `html` see Update 3.

Comment: Are you sure you want the height to be more than 100%? This makes scrolling a living hell for users

Comment: @Adrift No, that would make the `html` only `100% height` of the browser window..

Comment: @Markasoftware In some cases the content will be higher than `100% browser window height`, I want the elements `html, body, .container` to expand with them accordingly; they won't if I make it `100%`

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `html, body {height: 100%;}`? This is used all the time with pages that could be the full height of the viewport (or not). What happens when you use this that you're not wanting? http://jsfiddle.net/rpz4rd4c/6/ (Note you see no black.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish When the content of the page exceeds the browser height it will leave the `html, body` div. That is problematic.

Comment: This seems to work (according to Chrome style styles)? http://jsfiddle.net/rpz4rd4c/9/

Comment: I've looked for a solution for this forever and have never had any luck. Is there a specific thing that you are trying to accomplish with the 100% height that there might be a workaround for? (ie, a 100% height sidebar, background image, etc?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work with Chrome:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rpz4rd4c/10/

Of course, this means the `html` element never takes the full child's height (only the viewports). Hopefully that's not an issue.

Comment: Thank you. Its' unfortunately buggy with a plugin i'm using. But i'm sure I will find a work around. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Viewport units to the rescue! The `vh` unit in CSS works relative to viewport height regardless of parent elements and all that fuss. Here's the CSS you should put on the body:

```
body{
    min-height:100vh;
    margin:0;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/rpz4rd4c/3/ for my working example

**EDIT:** for your other elements that also need to be at least 100% height, just add `min-height:100vh`  to their CSS styling as well. Thanks @misterManSam!

Comment: In combination of other dividers though, this will not solve the problem. Do you suggest using `min-width: 100vh` in every divider that requires 100% or larger height? Also, this is not supported by a lot of browsers, is it?

Comment: Yes, I do suggest that, if you're you need to set their height to at least the page height. And, it's supported by virtually all modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: But I require some elements to be relative to this specific divider. That doesn't seem to work. __UPDATE__ http://jsfiddle.net/rpz4rd4c/7/

Comment: @Removed - if you want to go down this path, don't apply any height to the html or body at all. [In this example](http://jsfiddle.net/onh1dv8w/), each container gets at least 100% of the viewport height and will resize with its contents.

Answer (score -1):

Without really understanding the why, perhaps this is what you're looking for?

html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='inner'>
        <!-- your content here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

css:

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper{
  height:100%;
  overflow:scroll;
  background:#f9f9f9;
}
```

The html and body are always 100% height, and no matter what the content length it will still scroll. Not sure on the side effects of locking the html/body scrolling (lots of potential issues) however, so I'd be wary.

Example: http://codepen.io/jessekernaghan/pen/GocHg